# How to stop my website from redirecting to another page?

Tags: sql, wordpress, cpanel

We are having a website such as example.com but it is keep on redirecting to example.com/wordpress.

Even though we removed all files from public_html folder and just placed index.html file in public_html folder. It is not accessing index.html instead showing an error as page not found and redirecting to example.com/wordpress even though there is no wordpress folder and files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Clear the browser cache
- Check the domain is pointing correctly to public_html folder
- Try creating index.php file inside the public_html folder to echo some content